# What are some rules that native speakers instinctively know about English that non-native speakers usually don't?

Tags: english, grammar

For example, the famous tweet quoting Forsyth,

> [A]djectives in English absolutely have to be in this order: opinion-size-age-shape-colour-origin-material-purpose Noun. So you can have a lovely little old rectangular green French silver whittling knife. But if you mess with that word order in the slightest you’ll sound like a maniac. It’s an odd thing that every English speaker uses that list, but almost none of us could write it out. And as size comes before colour, green great dragons can’t exist.

Are there other unspoken rules similar to this, that are often hard to explain or put into words because they just "feel right"?

Comment: I think this is likely way too broad. There are so many very subtle English peculiarities that first language English speakers instinctually follow but are unlikely to be taught in language schools etc.

Comment: Native English speakers often know the rule for _a_ ~ _an_ (_a_ before consonants, _an_ before vowels), but they often don't know what vowels and consonants are -- they think they're letters in English spelling, instead of sounds. And none of them know that the same rule applies to /ðə/ ~/ði/ (/ðə/ before consonants, /ði/ before vowels) - _the man_ vs _the old man_.

Comment: And that's just phonology. Virtually everything in English syntax is unknown cognitively to native speakers, but they clearly understand the rules in terms of following them, even though they can't state them.

Answer (score 4):

The countability of nouns and the transitivity of verbs are among the things dictionaries of English aimed at learners always make note of while native-speaker dictionaries do so only occasionally. It's not uncommon for conversations to take place about *evidences*, *softwares*, *informations*, *discussing about something*, etc. among non-native speakers, and often only when a native speaker joins them is it perceived as a problem (even if some of them know it's nonstandard).

Definiteness works differently across languages, so e.g. someone used to saying *l'argent* in French might say *the money* when a native speaker would say simply *money*. Prepositions also pose a great obstacle to learners (*in/on/at*, *of/for/to/with*, etc.).

[Popular questions on the English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Frequent) will hopefully give you a good sense of the kinds of things learners find hard to grasp.

Answer (score 3):

Instinct doesn't play a role in human language, instead native speakers have automatic unconscious knowledge of a cognitive system ("the rules") that allow them to understand and produce utterances. The prescriptive rules that are taught either in high school grammar classes and college composition classes for native speakers (if there are such things) are unrelated to to internalized grammar that native speakers of a language have acquired.

Second language learners are able to acquire a (substantial) subset of the rules of a language, such as English, indeed if a second language learner starts young enough they can become fluent native speakers of the language. Those who learn the language as adults can probably mostly acquire the rules of the language, except that rules of pronunciation are generally only imperfectly learned if acquisition starts significantly post-pubescently.

Basically, all rules of grammar are "unspoken" at least from the native speaker's perspective, and the explicitly-taught rules taught to second language learners are mnemonic aids that allow the learner to intuit their own system of rules, which with any luck is pretty similar to the system of native speakers. There are also a number of prescriptive rules where it is decreed that X-Y is right and Y-X is incorrect, but you do in fact observe both possibilities. Myriad decrees regarding proper verb form are very often violated ("If I was lucky..." vs "If I were lucky..."; "We should of (have) gone"). It is likely that second-language speakers will have acquired the prescribed form compared to native speakers of English, to the extent that they learned the language through explicit instruction, because the version of the language that they are exposed to is more likely to conform to those norms, as opposed to native speakers who learn the pattern from how people actually talk.

The status of the adjective-order generalizations as real rules of grammar is controversial in linguistics. In fact, there can be semantic differences involved in adjective order, see for example "My class has a shortest Italian student" vs. "My class has an Italian shortest student" which means something else. Instead, observed order is likely to be  epiphenomenal, stemming from pragmatic factors.

Comment: I think the discussion around adjective order is only about the unmarked order of adjectives. Deviations from this are marked in that they indicate that part of the adjective-noun chain is being treated as a category in its own right. I.e. going back to the dragons that are both green and great in the OP, a great green dragon is simply one that is green and great, whilst a green great dragon implies that "great dragons" are some pertinent category (perhaps a specific species)

Comment: "native speakers have automatic unconscious knowledge of a cognitive system ("the rules") that allow them to understand and produce utterances." Native speakers, when they are children, internalize knowledge of grammar from what they hear from others around them. So, if you speak AmE and are "uneducated and working class", you might say "He don't" and "She don't" whereas if you are "educated and middle class",  you won't. No judgment, just a fact. But I am not sure that what we speak is "unconscious". Perhaps saying unaware of grammar is less tendentious.

Comment: Talking is as unconscious as walking, which is learned at about the same time and in about the same way. Speaking consciously is quite stressful for many people.